# LCA from children using bottom up approach?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, graph-traversal

I'm interested in finding the LCA of two distinct Nodes in a (not necessarily binary) tree from the bottom up without using depth.

How would I go about traversing the tree, starting from any 2 arbitrary nodes, each of which points to a previous node as shown without a depth variable?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor (which is the place you reach if you enter "lowest common ancestor" into the search bar at Wikipedia).  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question research you've done.  In general, if your question is answered on the obvious spot on Wikipedia, you haven't done enough research before asking.

Comment: There are also a list of references on that Wikipedia page (and most pages) -- for future reference, reading them is often very helpful in finding algorithms.  Anyway, now you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one approach. Given leaves $\alpha,\beta$, first compute the depths $d(\alpha),d(\beta)$ of both leaves (to compute the depth of a leaf, measure how many times you need to apply the parent operation until you reach the root). Suppose without loss of generality that $d(\alpha) \geq d(\beta)$. Replace $\alpha$ with $\alpha$'s $(d(\alpha) - d(\beta))$'th parent. The least common ancestor doesn't change, and so we can assume without loss of generality that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are at the same depth.

If $\alpha = \beta$, then $\alpha$ is the least common ancestor. Otherwise, replace both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with their parents. This doesn't change the least common ancestor. Continue like that, and eventually you will find the least common ancestor.

Comment: The running time is $O(d(\alpha) + d(\beta))$, so it is $O(h)$, where $h$ is the height of the tree. In particular, it is $O(n)$, where $n$ is the size of the tree.